# Access values of structs from a pointer in a struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, hashmap

I'm going to try and keep this as brief as possible.
So I have two structs:

```
typedef struct someStruct named;
struct someStruct {
    void *key;                  
    void *value;                    
};
typedef struct anotherStruct namedToo;
struct anotherStruct {
    named **table;          
    unsigned int size;          
};
```

Okay great, now ingore any possible mistakes above, this is uneditable code.

Now I have two methods:

```
namedToo *init(float ignoreThis) {
    namedToo *temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(namedToo)); //some memory for the second struct
    temp->table = malloc(sizeof(named)*100); //lets say this 100 is for 100 buckets/cells/named elements
    return temp;
```

Method 2:

```
int insert(namedToo *temp, void* key, void* value) {
     temp->table[0]->key = key; //My problem, I need to access the value and key inside named from the pointer inside namedToo. How can I do this?
}
```

The comment has my problem : 
My problem, I need to access the value and key inside named from the pointer inside namedToo. How can I do this? I would need to change and grab value/key on their own from time to time.

Comment: The name `table` suggests it should be treated as a 2D array, not a 1D array.  Is that the case?

Comment: Its a possibility, but not necessary, the reason for table is because its remnant of a hash table/map. The first struct has a pointer in it which points to another element for separate chaining, though I haven't included it here. Lets assume names used are completely arbitrary. @dbush

Comment: `init` doesn't correctly initialize `table` as a pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The declaration `named **table;` says `table` is pointer to a pointer to `named`, or alternately an array of pointer to `named`.  The latter is you seem to intend.

This allocation:

```
temp->table = malloc(sizeof(named)*100);
```

Allocates space for 100 `named`, but what you need are 100 `named *`, and each of those must point to a `named`.  Given the definition of `named` this is likely enough space, however at this point you have an array of uninitialized pointers.  Attempting to access them results in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case manifests as a core dump.

You need to allocate space for an array of pointers, then initialize each of those to a single dynamically allocated instance of `named`.  So you should be allocating space like this:

```
int i;
temp->table = malloc(sizeof(named *)*100);
for (i=0; i<100; i++) {
    temp->table[i] = malloc(sizeof(named));
}
```

Then your `insert` method should work properly.

Comment: Yep, that sums it up. An alternative allocation of pointers using the struct being allocated itself would be `temp->table = malloc(sizeof *(temp->table) * 100);`

Comment: @dbush Perfect, yes this solves my problem. Thank you. Just to understand, in this case, what is the difference between (named *) and (named), and why the need to allocate space to both? Sorry I'm new to C, pointers and memory allocation is really challenging for me to understand, coming from java.

Comment: @Monkleys `named *` is a pointer to a `named`, while `named` is an instance of the structure itself.  Two sets of allocations are necessary because `table` is defined as `named **`, i.e. a pointer-to-pointer.